# Create Runtime reporting in Selenium

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

I am trying to create run time reporting mechanism in for my automation test cases which are developed in Selenium using Java as language and TestNG as framework.

I am storing all my test case result and its details in MySQL database.

I am able to insert test results in DB but not sure how to publish them in UI. So can you please help me in letting me know step by step what all things I should do in order to publish my test results in UI[ also I have never done any front end coding ]. Also do i need to configure/install any kind of webserver.

Thanks in advance,
Sunny

Comment: Test NG automatic generates test report , do you want to generate custom report?

Comment: TestNG report will come when automation is over..i want to have some kind of run time reporting....

Comment: Through TestNG its not possible. Even if the test crash, there is no chance of getting the reports.

Comment: @ Prashanth...I never said i want to implement runtime reporting through testNG

Comment: okay; the below answer gives you the expected result I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply create a PHP file which returns the data from your mySQL table and call this page periodically by AJAX, for example in every 10 seconds.

Here you can find a very basic example for it: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp